# How to connect to the running windwows application with pywinauto?

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto, window-handles

I'm having a problem connecting to a running window application that was opened in the browser via citrix links. I have a snippet of the window name here.
How can I find out if pywinauto can see the running window of the application?

Which code do I need for this?

My code doesn't work:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application


app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title = 'Applikationsmenü - Produktivsystem der 
LogSys-Applikation für XY')
```

[image: Running Appliciation]

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: You have to add parameter `timeout=10` explicitly to `connect(...)` method call. This is known issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how the code would be then look like?

Comment: pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

Comment: `print([w.window_text() for w in Desktop(backend="uia").windows()])`

Answer (score 0):

Use process Id, see sample code

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto.application import Application

# add your exe name here; you can get via Task Manager
yourExeName = ""  

# get PID of your running process
pid = application.process_from_module(module = yourExeName)

# use Pid to connect
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(process = pid)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I don't have an EXE for it. It is a Citrix dialog window. It looks like this in Task Manager: (added it to the top post)

Comment: How can i get the exe name from task manager?

Comment: pid = Application.process_from_module(module = yourExeName)
AttributeError: type object 'Application' has no attribute 'process_from_module'

Comment: use application, not Application...

Comment: For getting exe name from Task Manager... Right-click on the BLUE highlighted on the screenshot and select Go to Details... you should see the EXE name there(in Details Tab)...

Comment: Thanks @Sachin , yes i find the way, but my opend window has No Go to Details Option. I think it Just a window which was Open by citrix proces. And there ist No exe for this window

Comment: Oh, is it inside Citrix? Now I see you mentioned it. Citrix, RDP or other remote connection software doesn't provide GUI information to local machine. You have to run script on remote machine. We have a guide for it: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html

Comment: Citrix is not mentioned there, but complexity is the same, maybe even more. I didn't try exactly with Citrix. It should be in theory the same as for Remote Desktop, but Citrix has no options which RDP has.